# Isolated jest integration tests using DB transaction

Tags: node.js, jestjs, knex.js

in our project we have integration tests written with Jest which first setup data in DB, run test logic and then do the teardown.

Because these tests can run in parallel we have to create setup with unique values (eg. emails have to be unique) for each test so it works with unique keys in the DB.

Our idea is to mock DB layer and create a new transaction for every test before it starts and later rollback it so we do not have to worry about unique test setup and teardown.

I was able to mock our DB layer (currently we use knex) using following code but I do not know how to create a transaction at the beginning of the test, save it to some "test scope variable" and then access it and rollback it.

```js
jest.mock('db.service', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('db.service');

  return {
    ...originalModule,
    db: jest.fn(() => {
      // this db() function is called every time when we work with DB and returns knex instance
      // maybe something like originalModule.db().transacting(tx);
      return originalModule.db();
    }),
  };
});
```

Does anybody please have an idea how to do it?